# Resizing string array in hash-table

Tags: c++, hashtable

I'm learning hashing right now. I am trying to resize my hash-table when it is >=80% filled. But every time i try to resize it, i get undefined behaviour or it crashes.

I tried to make a new String array with more fields and then i deleted the old one but that wasn't working.

hashtable.h

```cpp
class hashtable
{
    public:
        hashtable();
        void insert(string);
        void resize_array();
        int hashfunction(string str);
        string* getArray();

    private:
         int elemts_in_array;
         int table_size;
         string* T;
};
```

hashtable.cpp

```cpp
hashtable::hashtable()
{
    // your code (start with a capacity of 10)
    table_size = 10;
    elemts_in_array = 0;
    string *array = new string[table_size];
    T = array;
}


void hashtable::insert(string key)
{
    string* array = getArray();
    int hkey=hashfunction(key);

    float filled = float(elemts_in_array)/float(table_size);
// When the array is more than 80% filled resize it and double the table_size
    if(filled >= 0.8)
    {
        cout << "Resizing Array.." << endl;
        resize_array();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<table_size;i++)
    {
// if the field is empty insert it, else go +1
        if(array[(hkey+i)%table_size] == "")
        {
            array[(hkey+i)%table_size] = key;
            elemts_in_array++;
            break;
        }
        if(array[(hkey+i)%table_size] == key)
        {
          // it is the same element
            break;
        }
    }
}


void hashtable::resize_array()
{
    int old_table_size =table_size;
    table_size*=2; // double the size of the hashtable
    string* old_array= new string[table_size]; // save the old array entries
    old_array = T;

// Apply the old entries in old_array
    for(int i=0; i<table_size;i++)
    {
        old_array[i]= T[i];
    }

//create a new array with double size
    string *new_array = new string[table_size];
//delete the old T
    delete[] T;
    T = new_array;

//re-hash the old entries into the new array with double size (HERE I GOT THE ISSUES)
    for(int i=0; i<table_size/2; i++)
    {
        insert(old_array[i]);
    }
}
```

sometimes my program went into a loop or it crashed. I really don't know why it is not working.

Comment: The most glaring offender is `old_array = T;` followed by `delete[] T;`, then finally a loop doing `insert(old_array[i]);` Once you `delete[] T` `old_array` is left with a dangling pointer, drilling into it will invoke UB. Rubbing salt, you also have a memory leak in that function, as `string* old_array= new...` is leaked on the very next line.

Comment: oh hehe i had looked straight past that assignment and found a bunch of other problems instead

Answer (score 0):

If you step through your program's execution with your debugger, you will probably spot an issue with your `resize_array` function.

When it copies the old table entries back to the newly allocated array, it uses the `insert` function.  This has some problems:

1. you might not get back the same ordering of the original values, due to the collision resolution;
2. the `insert` function increases the table size, thus it will end up thinking it has twice as many entries as you originally inserted.

Now, the crash could happen because `insert` will hit the table-increase limit again.  The cycle repeats until you either get a stack overflow or you run out of memory.

The proper way to copy back in your strings is this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < table_size / 2; i++)
{
    T[i] = old_array[i];
}
```

But then there's another problem that can crash before any of this happens.  You first saved your values like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<table_size;i++)
{
    old_array[i]= T[i];
}
```

Note that `table_size` has already been doubled and so you are going to access past the end of `T`.  You should have looped on `old_table_size` instead.

You also have some needless copying.  If you are going to reallocate `T`, then just do this:

```
void hashtable::resize_array()
{
    int old_table_size = table_size;
    table_size *= 2;

    string* old_T = T;
    T = new string[table_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < old_table_size; i++)
    {
        std::swap(T[i], old_T[i]);   // or in C++11 assign with std::move
    }
    delete[] old_T;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I have to re-hash the old entries with the new size so i have to use the insert function (i think) with the new table size.

Comment: Oh true.  Sorry, I shouldn't answer SO questions while I'm compiling.  My mind is not 100% here.  You're right.  So in that case, no copy is necessary but you must at least reset the number of contained elements to zero before doing the inserts.